# I want to create a matlab program that stores and increment the value inside the array after certain events

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:2

    dice_roll_1=randi(6);
    dice_roll_2=randi(6);
    player_dice_roll=dice_roll_1+dice_roll_2;
    player_position=player_dice_roll;

end
```

For the second round I want the array `player_position` to have its elements added by the new values of `dice_roll_1` and `dice_roll_2`.

Comment: `player_position` is a scalar (technically, a 1-by-1 array), I see no arrays here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bring the `player_position` variable outside your loop and initialize it to a value equal to `0`. Then, within each loop, you increase it's total value adding the result of the dice rolls:

```
player_position = 0;

for i=1:2
    dice_roll_1 = randi(6);
    dice_roll_2 = randi(6);
    player_dice_roll = dice_roll_1+dice_roll_2;
    player_position = player_position + player_dice_roll;
end
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'm working on a monopoly script in matlab so yeah i needed that.

Answer (score 0):

here's a version without for loops:

```
% this makes 10 rolls of two dice, but change 10 to whatever # you want
dice_rolls= randi(6,2,10);
```

then

```
sum(dice_rolls) % is the sum of each pair
```

and

```
cumsum(sum(dice_rolls))
```

is the cumulative sum of rolls in each round...

For example:

```
dice_rolls= randi(6,2,3)
```

dice_rolls =

```
 5     4     6
 2     5     6
```

these are the 3 rolls of 2 dice (lucky 6 6 at the last roll)

Then >>

```
cumsum(sum(dice_rolls))
```

ans =

```
 7    16    28
```

you can see the answer is: (roll 1), (roll 1 + roll 2), (roll 1 + roll 2 + roll 3)

that's what you wanted right?

Comment: Thanks. This is want i want to make, but it's not working because of the dimensions.                                                                         player_position=0;

for i=1:3
dice_roll_1=randi(6)
dice_roll_2=randi(6)
player_dice_roll(i)=dice_roll_1+dice_roll_2

player_position(i)=player_position(i) + player_dice_roll(i)

Comment: I dont understand, I 'll show an example and please relate to it'

Comment: Thanks!  let me send you a link to what i really want to do. It's a monopoly script.

Comment: Here is the link and thanks for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47664370/9058602

Comment: you did not relate to the example I wrote. I'm nor going to read the question in the link https://i.imgur.com/L77l5Of.gif

Comment: The think is in the code in the link, it's a game so i need a loop that's why.